# get continue indexed array from php array_slice

Tags: php, slice

i am slicing dynamic values from php array_slice function. Getting repeated values like 
 array(0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3) but want like array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8); please give me solution

**EDIT**

```
if($rooms == 2) { 
    $roomTwoAdults = array_slice($adults,0,2); 
    $roomTwokids = array_slice($childrens,0,2); 
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($roomTwokids);$i++) { 
        $roomTwokidsAge = array_slice($kidsAge,0,$roomTwokids[$i],TRUE); 
        print_r($roomTwokidsAge); 
    } 
}
```

i am passing values to

```
array(3,6,9,12)
```

dynamically but i am getting result array is

```
Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 6 [2] => 9 ) Array ( [0] => 3 )
```

Comment: `array_merge`???  If you're talking keys and not values.

Comment: Show your input array, the actual values you're using for array_slice, and what you expect to get from that array

Comment: provide some code to illustrate the problem

Comment: if($rooms == 2)
  {
 $roomTwoAdults   = array_slice($adults,0,2);
 $roomTwokids  = array_slice($childrens,0,2); 
   
 for($i=0; $i<sizeof($roomTwokids);$i++)
{
$roomTwokidsAge = array_slice($kidsAge,0,$roomTwokids[$i],TRUE);
print_r($roomTwokidsAge);  
}
   
}
i am passing values to array(3,6,9,12); dynamically but i am getting result array is 

Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 6
    [2] => 9
)
Array
(
    [0] => 3
)

Comment: So what is the result that you ___expect___ to get?

Comment: `array(3,6,9,12)` is working exactly as you posted it. you don't specify keys, so PHP assigns them based on the lowest/first available numeric index, which is 0. if you want different keys, then specify them yourself: `array(0 => 3, 42 => 6, 500 => 9, 'foo' => 12)`.

Comment: can i increase index dynamically based on input value?

Comment: What do you want the index to be?

Answer (score 0):

well, supposing your array is so composed:

```
$array = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
```

array_slice function gives you part of it, for example:`

```
array_slice($array, 7);
```

gives you [7, 8]

```
array_slice($array, 3, 5);
```

gives you [3, 4, 5]

you could have access to values at the end, accessing it with negative integer, like:

```
array_slice($array -1, 1);
```

gives you [8]

how is it composed your array? if it is like in my example you can use this:

```
$new_array = array_slice($array, 0);
```

or, if you like negative numbers:

```
$new_array = array_slice($array, -9);
```

assuming you want to get these arrays:

```
Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 6 [2] => 9 ) Array ( [3] => 12 )
```

you could use this code:

```
if($rooms == 2) { 
    $roomTwoAdults = array_slice($adults,0,2); 
    $roomTwokids = array_slice($childrens,0,2); 
    for($i=0; $i<key($roomTwokids) + 1;$i++) { 
        $roomTwokidsAge = array_slice($kidsAge,0,$roomTwokids[$i],TRUE); 
        print_r($roomTwokidsAge); 
    }
    // key of array returns key of the element pointed by internal pointer: in our case, 0
    for($i=0; $i<key($roomTwokids) + 1;$i++) { 
        // get the third position of the array (value is 12) -> array_slice($kidsAge, 3) <- 3 is the value of $roomTwokids[0]
        $roomTwokidsAge = array_slice($kidsAge,$roomTwokids[$i], true); 
        print_r($roomTwokidsAge); 
    }
}
```

using that as array:

```
array(3, 6, 9, 12);
```

Comment: find bellow code i am passing dynamic values to loop staring from 0(zero) upto dynamic length which i have given in loop. my question is how can i get index continuously?   

   for($i=0; $i<sizeof($roomTwokids);$i++)
   {
    $roomTwokidsAge = array_slice($kidsAge,0,$roomTwokids[$i],TRUE);
    print_r($roomTwokidsAge);  
   }

Comment: ok then, every loop you do, you will consider each position of roomTwokids, right? every loop roomTwokidsAge will be overwritten by next loop because you don't save previous result anywhere.
so, during the last loop, roomTwokids[$i]'s value will be the value of the last position of that array. array_slice($kidsAge,0,**last value of roomTwokids array**,TRUE) will be all the values in kidsAge from position 0 to value in the last position of roomTwokids. is it right?

Comment: I have 5 rooms if rooms value 2 slicing 2 children for room 1 and 2 i am looping children value and their age for fist room children value 3 age 3,6,9 second room children 1 age 12 for loop is here 

   $roomTwokids  = array_slice($childrens,0,2); 
   
   for($i=0; $i<sizeof($roomTwokids);$i++)
   {
    $roomTwokidsAge = array_slice($kidsAge,0,$roomTwokids[$i]);
    print_r($roomTwokidsAge);
   }
but i am getting below result 

Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 6
    [2] => 9
)
Array
(
    [0] => 3
)

Comment: i am getting blank screen.i checked it key($roomTwokids) is 0